# codeigniter ajax loader error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with my ajax loader in CI.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
        <script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submit').click(function() {
        var form_data = {
        username : $('.username').val(),
        password : $('.password').val(),
      };
      var loader = $('<img/>', {
        'src':'assets/img/ajax-loader.gif',
        'id':'message'
      });
      loader.insertAfter($(this));

      //.removeClass().addClass('loader').html('<img src="assets/img/ajax-loader.gif">').fadeIn(1000);
      $.ajax({ //
        url: "<?php echo site_url('login/ajax_check'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        async : false,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(msg) {
          $('#ajax_loader').remove();
          $('#message').html(msg);
        }
      });
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**c_login.php controller**

```
  function ajax_check() {
            //if($this->input->post('ajax') == '1') {
            if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Please fill in the fields');
                    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                        echo validation_errors();
                    } else {
                        $this->load->model('m_access');
                        $user = $this->m_access->check_user($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password'));
                    if($user) {
                        echo 'login successful';
                        //echo '<img src="assets/img/loader-bar.gif"> Hello!';
                        //$this->load->view('welcome');
                    } else {
                        echo 'unknown user'; //
                        //echo ' <img src="assets/img/icon_error.gif"> Username or password not valid';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem is, it's just displaying the loader infinitely.

What I want to do is, if the user is valid, will show the loader.gif and then redirect to main page else will display the username or password incorrect. What is wrong with my code? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that function ajax_check is called?

Comment: @donkeydown Yes ajax_check is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you named your loader as "message" instead of creating a "message" new element and name your loader as "ajax_loader".

```
var loader = $('<img/>', {
    'src':'assets/img/ajax-loader.gif',
    'id':'ajax_loader'
});
var message = ...
    ...
    'id':'message'
```

.

```
success: function(msg) {
    $('#ajax_loader').remove();
    $('#message').html(msg);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply, though I followed your correction, I still get the same result. Please have a look at my updated post. I added my controller class there.

Comment: @Dunkey - then, are you sure that you are getting a 200 response on ajax request, check your web-developer tool (like firebug) to make sure that your request is valid

Comment: You may change your php code to `function ajax_check() { echo 'reply' }` just to make it reply something for sure and see what happens.

Comment: It's working already, but the showing of the loader is not working.